# Maven - changing defaulted argument to other pom.xml defined

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, pom.xml

I have a test distribution for testNG running with maven. Whenever I need the default test distribution, I can do so and whenever I need just a few or only one test, I can change something like the -`DoverallParams` in command line (although names have been changed).

```
<properties>
    <param1>x</param1>
    <param2>y</param2>
    <param3>z</param3>
    <defaultParams>${param1},${param2}</defaultParams>
    <defaultParams2>${param1},${param3}</defaultParams2> <-This does not exist yet!
    <overallParams>${defaultParams}</overallParams>
</properties>
```

I now need to use a different set of tests for a different platform, without duplicating or branching the project.
So the idea would be adding a `defaultPrams2` and somehow selecting it in the command line.

**Question**:

*Is there any way to have something in the command line which would make me select `defaultParams2` as the `overallParams`? Simpler yet, is there a way to reference a pom property in command line?
Do you have another idea on how to do this?*

Comment: I find your question a bit unclear. What exactly do you want to do and what is the duplication you're talking about?

Comment: I was saying that I cannot branch the project or just duplicate it physically and modify the pom.xml file to contain different values. It is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to have something in the command line which would make me select `defaultParams2` as the `overallParams`?

Yes, [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) can help you on that.

You could have in your pom the following:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>meaningful-name-here</id>
        <properties>
            <overallParams>${defaultParams2}</overallParams>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you could invoke Maven from command line as following:

```
mvn clean install -Pmeaningful-name-here
```

Basically, the `-P<id>` option will activate the profile above which will then override the value of the `overallParams` property and as such switch to the `defaultParams2` value at runtime and on demand.

This approach is less error prone than the following:

```
mvn clean install -DoverallParams=params
```

Where you would need to type each and every time the required parameters (and as such override on demand the value of `overallParams`). Just choose a better (and shorter) id than `meaningful-name-here` :)

> is there a way to reference a pom property in command line?

Yes, via explicit override (`-D`) or via profiles (`-P`) as described above.

Comment: The second question was Is there a way to reference a pom property as the value of another pom property in command line. IE we have defaultParams2 which already contains some properties and we want to assign that defaultParams2 to overallParams. So something like -DoverallParams= defaultParams2 instead of what it already does in the pom, where <overallParams>${defaultParams1}</overallParams> is possible.

Comment: Thank you for the profile part, anyway. I will try it and consider it a better solution anyway.

Comment: @CosminO you can actually use a property as value (or part of the value) of another property in Maven, as you actually also mentioned in your question, but you actually want to assign values between properties from command line like in your pom p1=a, p2=b, then from command line you would like to say p2=p1?